# How to get an attr value by class name and filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of inputs like this :

```
<input cat-id="13" cart-id="11" coupon-property_id="0" pay-user="7800" off="61" price="20000" coupon-id="16669" max-buy="100" name="cart-quantity" class="cart-quantity info-coupon" value="1" disabled="" type="text">
```

that them have different values .

now, I have two question :

1. how can i get `cat-id` value by using jquery ?

   ```
   function removeInCart(id){

   var cart_id = $('.cart-quantity .info-coupon').filter('input[cart-id='+id+']').attr();
     }
   ```

it returns a jquery error.

2. Did I properly define extra-values like `cart-id,cat-id coupon-propery_id ...` in input element ? or I should use `data-cart-id,data-cat-id ...` ?

Comment: Edit: You do not need it at all.. `$('.cart-quantity .info-couponinput[cart-id="'+id+'"]').attr();`

Comment: @RayonDabre No! we can pass selectors also

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: what is the `id` variable? is it `cart-id` or `cat-id`

Comment: @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy  to get value if it this here `13 `.

Comment: What you're doing is non-standard. Use `data-<attribute name>` instead. It may not solve your problem, but at least you'll have valid HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :remove space between `.cart-quantity` and `.info-coupon` and put attribute name in `attr()` function

```
var cart_id = $('.cart-quantity.info-coupon').filter('input[cart-id='+id+']').attr('cat-id');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.attr("cat-id")` ?

Comment: @apokryfos, yes. sorry my bad